# Are there any dependencies causing my \ref to not compile?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have learned that for labels and their respective references to compile and display correctly (for figures), it is necessary to have the `\label{}` **after** `\caption{}`, such as below:

```
Figure \ref{k2a}

\begin{figure}[h]
 % \caption{Isothermal thick film.}
  \begin{center}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= \columnwidth]{/home/userid/Research/Dissertation/2D/Periodic/k2a}
     \caption{When $\lambda = \lambda_{max}$ and M=35.1, Pr=7.20, S=100, G=1/3, rupture takes place at t=1280.0 (within 1\% or\citet{Krishnamoorthy1995a})}
     \label{k2a}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, are there any `.sty` / package dependencies that are not allowing my labels to compile right? I run `latex` twice but I receive a bunch of warnings such as `Reference  on page abc undefined on input line xxx.` and I get the dreaded `?` where the reference should be. The link to the figure through the question mark works though.

Here is my preamble, where I load all my packages. This occurs in a separate file.

does `\usepackage{caption}` have anything to do with this issue?

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}    
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelsep=period,labelfont=bf}
% --------
\usepackage{lscape}         % allows for landscape tables and figures
\usepackage{paralist}       % enancements to list environment
\usepackage{array}          % enhancements to array and tabular environments
\usepackage[usenames]{color}    
\usepackage{url}            
\usepackage{longtable}      % multipage tables
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{setspace}       % easy single or doublespacing
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}       % for listing computer code such as matlab
\usepackage[bw]{mcode}      % for matlab code with listings package
\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} % enhances bibtex citations
% \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}       % \singlespacing, \onehalfspacing, \doublespacing, ...

%%%%%%%%xyz%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{changepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%11022012-START%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Useful for file names with underscores in them
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grffile}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}} %To highlight text
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} %For footnotes
%%%%%%%%%%11022012-STOP%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: I don't know whether it helps, but you may try to put the `\label` _inside_ `\caption` like this: `\caption{When $\lambda = \lambda_{max}$ and M=35.1, Pr=7.20, S=100, G=1/3, rupture takes place at t=1280.0 (within 1\% or\citet{Krishnamoorthy1995a}).\label{k2a}}`. Notice that some of the packages are deprecated: `epsfig` (`graphicx` is enough), `color` (use `xcolor`). As well, I'm not sure whether the packages `subfig` and `sibfigure` are not clashing each other.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks for the tip! Also about the `subfig` and `subfigure` intereference... On a side note, would you know how I could label each figure in a minipage... or in a subfigure?

Comment: I had no problems compiling your float and \ref{} using your preamble (using MikTeX). I had to comment out \usepackage{mcode} since I did not have that package installed and also your \includegraphics since I do not have the figure. I would actually try to change the name of the graphics so that it is not the same as the the label. I finally renamed one of my eps-files to k2a.eps and your script still works without issues. So I do not think you have anything wrong in the code you have shown.

Comment: @PeterJansson That is very strange. I still have the error. Maybe I have a random key stroke somewhere...

Comment: Please, show how your `.aux` file looks after two compilations.

Comment: You really should try to make a minimal self contained example that shows the problem (while trying to make that you will probably find out what is causing the problem) Also, unrelated don't use `[h]` always use at least `[htp]` if you want to give latex a chance to avoid taking the float to the end of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It just started working fine **after ** I removed `\usepackage{caption}`. However now I have issues with the `\label{}` in my `\minipage{}` environments.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks for your constructive comment. Fortunately/unfortunately, I omitted the `\usepackage{caption}` and things work fine. However I have a completely different issue with `\minipage` which I think I need to look around online before posting here.

Comment: `minipage` and floats obviously cannot go along each other well. You _never ever_ place a float inside a minipage. If you want a `[h]`ere-placed float inside minipage, make it non-float and use the command `\captionof`.

Comment: @tohecz Thats food for thought! So I can use the `\captionof` command without `\usepackage{caption}`? And then use a `\label{}` inside `\captionof{}`??

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is very useful to provide a minimum working example (MWE) rather than copying your entire preamble (you did not include the `documentclass` in your code, but that's important).

For example, the following compiles fine with `LaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelsep=period,labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{k2a}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
%     \includegraphics[width= \columnwidth]{/home/userid/Research/Dissertation/2D/Periodic/k2a}
     \caption{When $\lambda = \lambda_{max}$ and M=35.1, Pr=7.20, S=100, G=1/3, rupture takes place at t=1280.0}
     \label{k2a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Incidentally, your entire preamble compiles fine on my machine with the `caption` package and the undefinend reference errors only occur because I don't have your citations.

A few other things, mentioned in the comments above and summarised here:

- Load `graphicx` instead of `epsfig`
- Load `xcolor` instead of `color`
- Load only `subfig` and not the depreciated `subfigure`
- You load `setspace` twice
- Don't use the `center` environement in the float. `centering` is enough
- Don't use `[h]` for placement unless you really need to, in which case `[h!]` is preferred (I think). Otherwise use something like `[htbp]`, which instructs LaTeX to try an place the float `here`, `top`, `bottom`, `page` in that priority.

The `l2tabu` [document](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) might provide an interest read, which discusses some of LaTeX' obsolote packages and options.

Comment: Instead of `subfigure` one could also use [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) which should play very nicely with `caption` (it's from the same author).

Comment: I accept this as an answer but I had the issue with non-compiling labels and references until I removed the `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: @drN Did you try updating your distribution?

Comment: @Jörg I am scared stiff that if I updated my latex distribution it would rewrite style files and put my dissertation (due quite soon) in jeopardy. What I generally do is, if I find that I lack a certain style file or package, I just put it in my dissertation folder...

Comment: @drN I am not sure that copying .sty files into your folder is good practice. One way to find out if your distribution is your issue is to install `TeXLive` (probably in portable mode), make a copy of your dissertation folder (without the sty files!) and try how that works.

Comment: @Jörg Thats good idea! I have a portable version installed on my netbook. Will probably try it out soon.